# How to resolve the error "com.android.internal.R cannot be resolved" when I using the android file 'MultiAutoCompleteTextView.java',

Tags: android

I want to implement my own Tokenizer base on the file
"MultiAutoCompleteTextView.java",

but I encounter an error "`com.android.internal.R cannot be resolved`" when I try to

import "`MultiAutoCompleteTextView.java`" to my project.

code:

```
public class MultiAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {
    private Tokenizer mTokenizer;

    public MultiAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MultiAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.autoCompleteTextViewStyle);
    }

    public MultiAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)     {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I haven't research any solutions to resolve this problem.How to correct "com.android.internal.R.attr.autoCompleteTextViewStyle" my own attr?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Can't use straight `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` as inside the SDK without declaring yourself?

Answer (score 12):

You could use

```
    public MultiAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      this(context, attrs,
        Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("autoCompleteTextViewStyle", "attr", "android");
    }
```

You cannot access id's of com.android.internal.R at compile time, but you can access the defined internal resources at runtime and get the resource by name. 
You should be aware that this is slower than direct access and there is no guarantee, that an internal resource will be available in future versions of android or in vendor-specific builds.

Comment: This wouldn't compile because calls to this() or super() must be the first line in a constructor.  You could however inline the id variable, ie:

`public MultiAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        this(context, attrs, Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("autoCompleteTextViewStyle", "attr", "android"));
    }`

Comment: Of course you are right, I modified the answer, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try copying the `attr` entry from [`attrs.xml`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml):

```
<attr name="autoCompleteTextViewStyle" format="reference" />
```

Add a `res/values/attrs.xml` to your application and put this line in there.
Finally, update your code to reference R from your package:

```
import com.your.package.R;
...
public MultiAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.attr.autoCompleteTextViewStyle);
}
```

Credit to [inazaruk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7068625/691281) for this procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the internal R with Java reflection.

To get autoCompleteTextViewStyle:

```
Class clasz = Class.forName("com.android.internal.R$attr") 
Field field = clasz.getDeclaredField("autoCompleteTextViewStyle");
field.setAccessible(true); 
int autoCompleteTextViewStyle= (int)field.get(null);
```

As said before, this way is a hack, usually Android provides a public style similar or same based on android.R

Comment: Reflection causes runtime penalties.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
    int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("config_sms_capable", "bool", "android");
    Resources res = Resources.getSystem();
    boolean configSMSCapable = res.getBoolean(id);
    TextView displayText = findViewById(R.id.displayText);
    String configSMSCapableString = configSMSCapable ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";
    displayText.setText("config_sms_capable = " + configSMSCapableString);
```

You need to specify the variable you want in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can import and reference from `internal`.
As a workaround download the references from the android source, and include in your own resources, and reference from your package.

Comment: Thank you foryour answer.I want to change some methods in this java profile to my methods,and import it into my project.
But I can'nt correct the error in this sentence
"this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.autoCompleteTextViewStyle)"

Comment: Have you tried rewriting to `com.android.R.attr.autoCompleteTextViewStyle` by taking down the internal package?

Comment: I meant to change it to 
`this(context, attrs, com.android.R.attr.autoCompleteTextViewStyle);` watch this closely as it differs from what you have in your code.

Comment: I don't think you can reference 'internal'... couldn't you call 'super(context, attrs)' instead?

Comment: @Pentium10: you get "package com.android.R does not exist"