# Problem copying AbsoluteLayout - com.android.internal.R cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-layout

I came to a problem that the only solutions is using a AbsoluteLayout (Just to show something at specific positions).

I'm trying to copy the AbsoluteLayout class to avoid it being removed on future releases and my app stop working.

I'm copying from here: http://www.google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.java&exact_package=android&q=AbsoluteLayout&type=cs

But getting this code, first, I changed all the mPadding(Direction) to getPadding(Direction), but there's still an error on the LayoutParams constructor:

```
    public LayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);
        TypedArray a = c.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                com.android.internal.R.styleable.AbsoluteLayout_Layout);
        x = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(
                com.android.internal.R.styleable.AbsoluteLayout_Layout_layout_x, 0);
        y = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(
                com.android.internal.R.styleable.AbsoluteLayout_Layout_layout_y, 0);
        a.recycle();
    }

com.android.internal.R cannot be resolved to a variable
```

How can I get these values? Or someone already has this class independently that don't belong to google wishes to keep on the API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to copy over `declare-styleable` entry from [`attrs.xml`](http://www.google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml&type=cs&l=2360):

```
<declare-styleable name="AbsoluteLayout_Layout">
    <attr name="layout_x" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="layout_y" format="dimension" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Just add `res/values/attrs.xml` file to your application and copy above lines there.

---

When this is done, update your code to reference `R` from your package:

```
import com.your.package.R;
...
public LayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(c, attrs);
    TypedArray a = c.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.AbsoluteLayout_Layout);
    x = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(
            R.styleable.AbsoluteLayout_Layout_layout_x, 0);
    y = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(
            R.styleable.AbsoluteLayout_Layout_layout_y, 0);
    a.recycle();
}
```